# Filter admin grid with custom render values Magento

Tags: magento, filter, grid, custom-controls, render

> i have created a custom grid in which one of the columns i have render
>   my custom date.On the basis of data i am returning
>
> yes or no

like below

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
            {
                $currentruleid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
                $value = (int)$row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
                $read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');    
                $write = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getConnection("core_write");  
                $query = "SELECT exclusive_coupon_id FROM mutually_exclusive
                WHERE rule_id ='$currentruleid' AND exclusive_coupon_id ='$value' ";  
                $result = $read->query($query);
                $affected_rows = $result->rowCount();
                if($affected_rows > 0){
                    return 'Yes';
                }
                else{
                    return 'No'; 
                    }   

            }
```

and in grid my column code is

```
$this->addColumn('', array(
    'header'   => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Exclusive'),
    'index'    => 'coupon_id',
    'width'    => '100',
    'type'     => 'options',
    'options'  => array(
        Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('No'),
        Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Yes')
    ),
    'renderer' => 'adminhtml/promo_quote_edit_tab_exclusivecoupons_grid_column_renderer_used',
));
```

> my renderer is returning accurate data
>
> and its showing in columns
>
> i need to filter also with yes or no. But filtering is not working.
>
> Can you please suggest me how can i do this.
>
> **thanks**

Answer (score 0):

i have check that but my renderer is not any direct field , its a custom data  like below is my renderer function

```
 public function render(Varien_Object $row)
            {
                $currentruleid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
                $value = (int)$row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
                $read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');    
                $write = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getConnection("core_write");  
                $query = "SELECT exclusive_coupon_id FROM mutually_exclusive
                WHERE rule_id ='$currentruleid' AND exclusive_coupon_id ='$value' ";  
                $result = $read->query($query);
                $affected_rows = $result->rowCount();
                if($affected_rows > 0){
                    return 'Yes';
                }
                else{
                    return 'No'; 
                    }   

            }
```

Comment: What if you get the data using  "$this->getCollection()->getData()" (inside "filter_condition_callback" function) and manage the array yourself depending upon the value selected and then reset collection data.

Comment: define "filter_condition_callback" function to your addColumn code using the link provided earlier and then inside that function get the collection data, process the array as per filter value and the set the collection back using the processed array.